# Creating a Stored Procedure to RANK Multiple Calculated Fields in MySQL 5.5.x

Tags: mysql

I know MS SQL fairly well (no expert), but am new to MySQL and can't quite get this to work.  I have a game that is composed of 6 stages which are timed. There are penalties for misses and procedural errors where each miss adds 5 seconds, and each procedural adds 10 seconds. 
I have to return a table that calculates total time for each stage, a rank for each stage's total time, total match time, total match misses, and overall match rank, in addition to all of the existing fields in the table, where a MatchId equals a specified match Id.  I should note that I am forced to use a mySQL 5.5x database, so no window functions such as RANK() function.

Here is my partial table, as I mentioned there are 6 stages per match.

```
+---------+--------+------------+---------+-------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| MatchID | UserID | CategoryID | Stg1Raw | Stg1M | Stg1P | Stg2Raw | Stg2M | Stg2P | ...-> Stg6p |
+---------+--------+------------+---------+-------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|       1 |      1 |          9 | 30.75   | NULL  | NULL  | 28.47   | 1     | NULL  | NULL        |
|       1 |      2 |         15 | 24.07   | 3     | NULL  | 22.20   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL        |
|       1 |      3 |         12 | 23.96   | NULL  | NULL  | 22.87   | NULL  | NULL  | NULL        |
|       2 |      2 |         15 | 25.72   | 1     | 1     | 28.95   | NULL  | 1     | NULL        |
+---------+--------+------------+---------+-------+-------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I am trying to create a stored procedure that takes in a parameter for matchId i.e. p_matchId and returns the scores for the match. What I can do is: create a stored procedure that calculates total time for each player for each stage, as well as calculating Total time for each player for all stages. I even figured out how to rank each stage as well as the total overall ranking in a standard query.  I just cant put it all together.

Here is my query for calculating stage and overall total scores

```sql
SELECT sc.*, 
(sc.stg1Total + sc.stg2Total + sc.stg3Total + 
sc.stg4Total + sc.stg5Total + sc.stg6Total) AS matchTotal 
FROM (SELECT m.Alias, c.Category, 
(ifnull(s.stg1M,0) + ifnull(s.stg2M,0) + ifnull(s.stg3M,0) + 
ifnull(s.stg4M,0) + ifnull(s.stg5M,0) + ifnull(s.stg6M,0)) AS mTotal, 
s.stg1Raw, s.stg1M, s.stg1P, ((s.stg1Raw + (ifnull(s.stg1M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg1P,0) * 10)) AS stg1Total, 
s.stg2Raw, s.stg2M, s.stg2P, ((s.stg2Raw + (ifnull(s.stg2M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg2P,0) * 10)) AS stg2Total, 
s.stg3Raw, s.stg3M, s.stg3P, ((s.stg3Raw + (ifnull(s.stg3M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg3P,0) * 10)) AS stg3Total, 
s.stg4Raw, s.stg4M, s.stg4P, ((s.stg4Raw + (ifnull(s.stg4M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg4P,0) * 40)) AS stg4Total, 
s.stg5Raw, s.stg5M, s.stg5P, ((s.stg5Raw + (ifnull(s.stg5M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg5P,0) * 50)) AS stg5Total, 
s.stg6Raw, s.stg6M, s.stg6P, ((s.stg6Raw + (ifnull(s.stg6M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg6P,0) * 60)) AS stg6Total 
FROM Scores s 
    INNER JOIN Members m
    ON s.ShooterId = m.id
    INNER JOIN Categories c
    ON s.CatId = c.ID
    where (MatchID =  p_matchId)) AS sc
```

I know there is probably a better/shorter way to write the above query so any suggestions on that would be appreciated as well.

I tried putting results of the above query into a temporary table and then run the ranking for each stage on the temp table, but mySQL doesn't appear to like the way I was attempting to do it.  What would be the shortest most efficient way to create this SP?

UPDATE: To clarify, How could I create a rank column for each of the following in the above sql statement: stg1Total, stg2Total, stg3Total, stg4Total, stg5Total, stg6Total, and matchTotal?

**UPDATE 2: I got it working but had to create multiple temp tables to get it to run, and achieve the desired results**

```sql
BEGIN

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE A SELECT sc.*, 
(sc.stg1Total + sc.stg2Total + sc.stg3Total + 
sc.stg4Total + sc.stg5Total + sc.stg6Total) AS matchTotal 
FROM
(SELECT m.Alias, c.Category, (ifnull(s.stg1M,0) + ifnull(s.stg2M,0) + ifnull(s.stg3M,0) + 
ifnull(s.stg4M,0) + ifnull(s.stg5M,0) + ifnull(s.stg6M,0)) AS mTotal,
s.stg1Raw, s.stg1M, s.stg1P, 
((s.stg1Raw + (ifnull(s.stg1M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg1P,0) * 10)) AS stg1Total,
s.stg2Raw, s.stg2M, s.stg2P, 
((s.stg2Raw + (ifnull(s.stg2M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg2P,0) * 10)) AS stg2Total,
s.stg3Raw, s.stg3M, s.stg3P, 
((s.stg3Raw + (ifnull(s.stg3M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg3P,0) * 10)) AS stg3Total,
s.stg4Raw, s.stg4M, s.stg4P, 
((s.stg4Raw + (ifnull(s.stg4M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg4P,0) * 40)) AS stg4Total,
s.stg5Raw, s.stg5M, s.stg5P, 
((s.stg5Raw + (ifnull(s.stg5M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg5P,0) * 50)) AS stg5Total,
s.stg6Raw, s.stg6M, s.stg6P, 
((s.stg6Raw + (ifnull(s.stg6M,0) * 5)) + (ifnull(s.stg6P,0) * 60)) AS stg6Total
FROM Scores s 
INNER JOIN Members m
ON s.ShooterId = m.id
INNER JOIN Categories c
ON s.CatId = c.ID
where (MatchID = p_matchId)) AS sc;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE B SELECT * FROM A;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE C SELECT * FROM A;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE D SELECT * FROM A;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE E SELECT * FROM A;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE F SELECT * FROM A;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE G SELECT * FROM A;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE H SELECT * FROM A;

SELECT Alias, Category, mTotal, stg1Raw, stg1M ,stg1P, stg1Total, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM B WHERE A.stg1Total>B.stg1Total)AS stg1Rnk, 
stg2Raw, stg2M ,stg2P, stg2Total, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM C WHERE A.stg2Total>C.stg2Total)AS stg2Rnk, 
stg3Raw, stg3M ,stg3P, stg3Total, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM D WHERE A.stg3Total>D.stg3Total)AS stg3Rnk, 
stg4Raw, stg4M ,stg4P, stg4Total, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM E WHERE A.stg4Total>E.stg4Total)AS stg4Rnk, 
stg5Raw, stg5M ,stg5P, stg5Total, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM F WHERE A.stg5Total>F.stg5Total)AS stg5Rnk, 
stg6Raw, stg6M ,stg6P, stg6Total, 
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM G WHERE A.stg6Total>G.stg6Total)AS stg6Rnk, 
matchTotal,
(SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM H WHERE A.matchTotal>H.matchTotal)AS oaRnk 
FROM A;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE A;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE B;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE C;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE D;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE E;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE F;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE G;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE H;

END
```

Its a little unruly, an probably not that performant, So I would still like to see a more efficient and performant method of achieving the same results.

Comment: Why do you don't show us what you have done so far, because without your tables and data it will be hard to test anything a temporary table  from your select is easy write CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_name SELECT  ....  and you have your temporary table

Comment: Looks like `stg[1-6]P` should be a separate table. You don't need to create stored procedures for [any|every]thing. If concerned about performance tables structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` and `EXPLAIN {query}`. Why stick to such an old database version?

Comment: The post is already long, so I just showed the pertinent table. The other tables are just joins to get the actual contestant and category names, and are not critical to creating the needed SP. Also It's not creating the Temporary table that is the problem, it is ranking multiple columns on the temporary table that I am having problems with. I didn't show my attempt because I think I am way off base.

Comment: @danblack, Yes a v8.x instances would be preferable. This is the back end to a HostGator website, which I inherited. HostGator can upgrade it to v5.7, but will not go any higher. Correct, this does not have to be an SP, I just thought it might make what I was trying to accomplish easier.